# Pivot a Table in PostgreSQL with Many Keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, entity-attribute-value

I am pivoting a table of the form `id`, `key`, `value` where there are many types of keys (130). There are too many keys to explicitly enumerate the types in the `crosstab()` call, or write out the `crosstab_N` function definition as recommended in the crosstab documentation:

```
    row_name TEXT,
    category_1 TEXT,
    category_2 TEXT,
        .
        .
        .
    category_N TEXT
);
```

How do I pivot this table into wide format with columns id, category_1, category_2, ... category_130? I find it hard to believe you can't pivot such tables in SQL without explicitly enumerating the column types. For example in R, using the `tidyverse` package I would just call `dataframe %>% spread(key=key, value=value)`

Answer (score 0):

> I find it hard to believe you can't pivot such tables in SQL without explicitly enumerating the column types.

A SQL query returns a *fixed* set of columns. SQL is a descriptive language, and you need to tell the database which columns you want in the resultset so it can understand your requirement, and build the proper query plan.

Typical solutions involve *dynamic* SQL: that is, use a query to generate the actual query string, *then* execute it. That's an additional level of indirection, that is can be somehow challenging.

One half-way solution is JSON. If you can live with a result where all key/pair values are aggregated in a single column a JSON object, you can do:

```
select id, json_object_agg(key, value) obj
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: having the key and value aggregated as json doesn't seem to add that much value tbh. how would the dynamic SQL approach solve the problem of retrieving the data in wide format?